# Keep a composite template editable after DocuSign signer complete and send to next or previous signer

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

The email routing has 3 signers and first 2 has signed composite template attached. The 3rd signer declines and DocuSign sends notification to '1' and '2'. I know '2' cannot alter anything in the template (including field values) but what option '2' has to start over the routing and send a new template with copied entries from last one. This is just to correct some entries in the first template sent to '3'.

As an alternate, can an excel spreadsheet in editable form be send to '3' where entries from last template (declined) are copied over and changes/addition are made.

I have tried attaching a second template which is exactly same as last one but routing did not work. '1' and '2' signed and '3' declined. Now it should start from '2' and go to '3'

Last routing was from '1' to '2' and from '2' to '3'. Now it should go from '2' to '3'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declining, the 3rd signer should ask the sender to "correct" the original envelope with whatever changes they have. This way, the envelope is still in play and may be eventually complete. When any signer declined - the entire envelope won't be complete anymore and a new one is required. 
If you enable the comments feature, the signers can communicate with the sender by leaving comments asking for changes etc. as a simple way to collaborate over the envelope.

Comment: The 2nd signer has already signed and that's how it went to next signer, #3, as next one in routing. So even if '3' ask sender to "correct" the original envelope, it won't help because '2' cannot edit the one he has already signed. I feel they must start a parallel process. 
The scenario is that '2' signs and template goes to next signer, '3', and this recipient has to decline so notification goes back to '2'. But by that time, '2' would not be able to edit anything as s/he already signed.

Comment: if the envelope is corrected, it can be routed again to both #1 and #2 if the sender chooses to do so.